# How to dedicate an Orchard Tenant to a Module?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms

I would like to use the Orchard infrastructure and an Orchard module as if it were a stansalone, dedicated application. This is not my design .decision

The way I see doing this, is on a multi-tenant enabled Orchard instillation, which is sort of what my employer uses for most web sites, is to create a tenant for my Recruitment site, and install the Recruitment module on this tenant. I would then need a way to set my module to be the start page on that Orchard tenant.

Is my general thinking OK, and how would I achieve the last part, i.e the start page?

Answer (score 0):

Use AliasUI to point the home page to your action.